# Getting the last mention with tweepy

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy

I want to make  that every time someone mentions me ('@name') it will print out to the console something, write it to the file, so it won't print the same mention twice, and wait till the next mention to appear.

**Function** is inside a class, if that matters.
myMentions = tweepy.Cursor(api.mentions_timeline).items()

```
def check_if_won(self, myMentions):
    openfile = open('lastid.txt', 'r')
    readfromfile = openfile.read()
    for mention in myMentions:
        if str(mention.id) not in readfromfile:
            try:
                writetofile = open('lastid.txt', 'a')
                writetofile.write(str(mention.id))
                writetofile.close()
                print(mention.text)
                print("$$$$$$$$$$$$ JACKPOT $$$$$$$$$$$$")
                print('\n')

            except Exception:
                pass
        else:
            pass
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: what's wrong with your code ? do you have an error ?

Comment: It was the function before it, I fixed it, thanks!